# Building ionic / cordova for iOS

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

Is there a way to build ionic apps in a way that I don't loose my xcode settings. Such as Provisioning profiles / build version / bundle identifier etc ?

Answer (score 0):

My quick fix is to not run ionic build and instead copy www folder in the previous build.